# nesting html tables issue

Tags: html, css

Hello I have nested a table inside a gridview(which I think is also basically a table) in asp.net ,but the thing is the table which is inside a cell leaves a space at  it edges ,(i.e from the wall of the grid view), I want this space to be minimized this is my grid view :

```
<FooterTemplate>
                    <table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="auto">
                     <tr><td><asp:Label ID="cl_crTotal" runat="server" CssClass="alLbl" /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr><td><asp:Literal runat="server" ID="closingTotC" ></asp:Literal></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                  </FooterTemplate>
```

I have also given the image ,please check
http://imgur.com/4ukGm&K8tRy  "this image"

PS:I know and hope this is a simple problem and would be easily solve just that I am new to this

Comment: Please, for the love of god, don't inflict improperly indented code on other programmers.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the code of that grid-view, I can only guess, that there are some paddings or margins set, which cause this behavior.

So for the grid cell, in which the table appears set

```
padding: 0;
```

and for the table itself set

```
margin: 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, its pretty simple. If you look at all your fields in the data, you see actually every field has it. Its called a padding.

What you should do is remove the padding from that cell. I am going to asume you dont want it in the rest of your table, so what you do is give the specific cell an id, and add in the css a rule to it saying it shouldnt receive any padding.

your html would look like this:

```
<body>
    <table>
         <tr>
              <td id="cell_id">somedata</td>
         </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

This would look something like this in your css file

```
 #cell_id { padding: 0px; }
```